# I would like to block a url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Htaccess is very sensitive when I try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} atirchad.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} atirchad. [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

to block the website atirchad.com, I get a 500 error on my own website

How can I block this site with two extensions? http://unab-frances.zz.mu/ ?

for the first url, I found:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://atirchad\.com$
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

and it does not error my website,

thank you

Comment: 2nd line of first code change `[NC,OR]` to `[NC]` and see if that stops the error, you also want to change the 3rd line `[F]` to `[F,L]`

Comment: thank you it is better now but not in Safari.

Comment: is there a difference between .* and (.*) ?

Comment: not really in that case, `.` matches anything but the end of a line but there is no end of line to match against in this case and `.*` repeats the previous match zero or more times so essentially on your example they would perform the same as well as `^` as suggest by anubhava. It may not be working on safari because you may have been cached does it work on any other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} [/.]atirchad\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: thank you, I cleaned the cache of my browsers and it only works with Google Chrome, so I used the IP of the website to Deny it and now it works in IE but not in Safari